# Access Outside Model Attribute in View layer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models, Movie and MovieCheckout and User. I made the correct associations between the classes.

In my index, I want to display each movie and who checked it out.

```
<% @movie.each do |movie| %>

   <% MovieCheckout.find_by movie_id: movie.id %> //I want to display MovieCheckout's user_id here.

<% end %>
```

I would like to know if there was a code that went something like this

```
<% MovieCheckout.find_by movie_id: movie.id %>.user_id
```

I was thinking of placing this logic in my MovieController

```
def index
    @total_movies = Movie.count
    @moviecheckout = MovieCheckout.find_by movie_id: movie.id
end
```

But I cannot reference movie outside of the view layer index.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute Ruby code outside the `<% %>` tags. This means the `.user_id` part is not evaluated.

Try something like this:

```
<% MovieCheckout.find_by(movie_id: movie.id).user_id %>
```

And indeed, this stuff doesn't belong in a View.

Comment: With the parenthesis, I get a nilClass.

Comment: See the answer by @ilan-berci for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MovieCheckout < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :user
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :checkouts, class_name: MovieCheckout, inverse_of: :movie
end

<% @movie.each do |movie| %>

   <% for co in movie.checkouts %>
     <%= co.user.name %>
   <% end %>

<% end %>
```